# MS Exchange errors to solve for installing on win server 2012

Tags: exchange, installation

For a home project I wish to install MS Exchange to a Windows Server 2012. The little server needs to know the following:

- shared calender between clients
- mailing
- shared ToDo.
  I try to achieve this using MS Exchange but I can't install due to some errors I enclose now. All my software are downloaded from my Microsoft Imagine account as I'm a student. The win server 2012 is just installed, nothing has been configured, guess that is the main reason why this isn't working. There are a lot of component missing. Do I have to install these one by one, or there is a solution that's quicker? How to make this work?

> Error: This computer isn't part of an Active Directory domain.
>
> Error: The user isn't logged on to an Active Directory domain.
>
> Error: This computer doesn't belong to a valid Active Directory site.
>   Check the site and subnet definitions.
>
> Error: This computer requires .NET Framework 4.5.2
>
> Error: There is a pending reboot from a previous installation of a
>   Windows Server role or feature. Please restart the computer and then
>   run Setup again.
>
> Error: You must be a member of the 'Organization Management' role
>   group or a member of the 'Enterprise Admins' group to continue.
>
> Error: You must use an account that's a member of the Organization
>   Management role group to install or upgrade the first Mailbox server
>   role in the topology.
>
> Error: You must use an account that's a member of the Organization
>   Management role group to install the first Client Access server role
>   in the topology.
>
> Error: You must use an account that's a member of the Organization
>   Management role group to install the first Client Access server role
>   in the topology.
>
> Error: You must use an account that's a member of the Organization
>   Management role group to install or upgrade the first Mailbox server
>   role in the topology.
>
> Error: You must use an account that's a member of the Organization
>   Management role group to install or upgrade the first Client Access
>   server role in the topology.
>
> Error: You must use an account that's a member of the Organization
>   Management role group to install the first Mailbox server role in the
>   topology.
>
> Error: Setup encountered a problem while validating the state of
>   Active Directory: Active Directory server  is not available. Error
>   message: Active directory response: The LDAP server is unavailable. 
>   See the Exchange setup log for more information on this error.
>
> Error: The 'IIS 7 Dynamic Content Compression' component is required.
>   Install the component via Server Manager.
>
> Error: The 'IIS 7 Digest Authentication' component is required.
>   Install the component via Server Manager.
>
> Error: The 'IIS 6 WMI Compatibility' component is required. Install
>   the component via Server Manager.
>
> Error: The 'Client Certificate Mapping Authentication' component is
>   required. Install the component via Server Manager.
>
> Error: The 'HTTP Redirection' component is required. Install the
>   component via Server Manager.
>
> Error: The 'Tracing' component is required. Install the component via
>   Server Manager.
>
> Error: The 'Request Monitor' component is required. Install the
>   component via Server Manager.
>
> Error: This computer requires the Microsoft Unified Communications
>   Managed API 4.0, Core Runtime 64-bit.
>
> Error: Either Active Directory doesn't exist, or it can't be
>   contacted.
>
> Warning: This computer requires the update described in Microsoft
>   Knowledge Base article KB2884597
>
> Warning: This computer requires the update described in Microsoft
>   Knowledge Base article KB2894875
>
> Warning: This computer requires the update described in Microsoft
>   Knowledge Base article KB2822241

Comment: Do your research please, and follow the error. You need an AD first, all other error are just pre req to install.

Comment: Doing that now, I believe it's in the roles.
I also added the purpose of this server. What other roles do you think I need?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1.) 
Microsoft Exchange relay on an working ActiveDirectory environment to store the elements in it. It looks like you do not have an ActiveDirectory environment prepared. So that would be the first step. As this is a kind of LAB environment you could follow this [howto](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/12370.windows-server-2012-set-up-your-first-domain-controller-step-by-step.aspx).

2.)
Install the [prerequisites](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb691354(v=exchg.160).aspx). To do that open powershell (run as admin) and enter:

```
Install-WindowsFeature AS-HTTP-Activation, Desktop-Experience, NET-Framework-45-Features, RPC-over-HTTP-proxy, RSAT-Clustering, RSAT-Clustering-CmdInterface, RSAT-Clustering-Mgmt, RSAT-Clustering-PowerShell, Web-Mgmt-Console, WAS-Process-Model, Web-Asp-Net45, Web-Basic-Auth, Web-Client-Auth, Web-Digest-Auth, Web-Dir-Browsing, Web-Dyn-Compression, Web-Http-Errors, Web-Http-Logging, Web-Http-Redirect, Web-Http-Tracing, Web-ISAPI-Ext, Web-ISAPI-Filter, Web-Lgcy-Mgmt-Console, Web-Metabase, Web-Mgmt-Console, Web-Mgmt-Service, Web-Net-Ext45, Web-Request-Monitor, Web-Server, Web-Stat-Compression, Web-Static-Content, Web-Windows-Auth, Web-WMI, Windows-Identity-Foundation, RSAT-ADDS
```

Comment: Thanks, doing that now. What other roles do I need for the purposes I mentioned?

Comment: The "roles" for example the "Organization Management" is created by a process called "Schema update" and this one run during the first Exchange installation inside an Active Directory environment. So at first you need to prepare an AD environment. My answer above has a link to a small howto.

Comment: By the way (its becoming off topic), the next step would be to setup email routing. As you do not have a fixed IP at home (where I assume your server is located now) you need to build a special construct which is explained [here](http://exchangeserverpro.com/exchange-server-dynamic-public-ip-address/) for example.

Comment: Thanks all of you, those lil tuts worth their weight in gold. 
Yes, I'm using VMWare on my laptop, nothing fancy here.

Comment: By the way, if this isn´t for education reasons most private persons who need such features start using [ExchangeOnline](https://products.office.com/en-us/exchange/compare-microsoft-exchange-online-plans) which offered the features you need for a small fee without the need that you install & administrate something on your own.

Comment: It's for education purposes only, after I completed these basically everything will be removed. I'm this noob because we weren't told how to do it, I don't even have basic networking knowledge :/