# Which roles in win server 2012 for my requirements?

Tags: windows-server-2012, remote-desktop, service

I have a couple of requirements that my system need:
A Windows server (Windows server 2012) with linux clients (OpenSUSE with multiple user accounts).
The services I have to implement:

- AD
- FTP
- Remote Desktop
- Bosses and Admins can use the remote desktop to access their computers, employees can't.
- Admins can access the server remotely
- Shared printer
- Monitor the server state (memory, logins, storage space)

The win server 2012 roles are [here](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/canitpro/2013/04/23/windows-server-2012-roles-features/).

Which roles to use for achieve what I need?
EDIT: I need to monitor the storage of the system, the users logged in, who accessed which file.

Comment: Hi yah. your exchange lab is already finished ? http://serverfault.com/questions/815532/ms-exchange-errors-to-solve-for-installing-on-win-server-2012 Please understand that there it's not to help on lab, you need to do your research before

Comment: Nope. That requirement was way beyound my laptop's capabilities and I could haggle to change in favour of a wee bit lighter one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Print and Document Services
2. Active Directory Domain Services
3. File and Storage Services
4. DNS if none other already exists.

Other than this you really need to describe more. Simple resource monitor provides information about system usage ram/cpu/disk/network and others.
What do you mean precisely as a Remote Desktop ... it's in system by default.
If you want to manage overall remote connection MMC then you would need Remote Desktop Services. As for separation of who can and can't access that up to your settings in OU/groups/users and assigning them to resource (another OU) which you want implement that on.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I edited the question on the monitoring.

Comment: then file and storage services will come with some level of help with that (it's not very deep though).